# Class A Emitter follower instantaneous power

Tags: power-amplifier, emitter-follower, class-a

I don't quite understand the explanation given in the book I'm reading. Why the maximum instantaneous power dissipated by Q1 is P=2Vcc*I at RL open? Also, why is the current ic1 constant I? Wouldn't the varying input signal will cause it to vary as well? As you can see in the graph below when vce1 = 2Vcc the current ic1 = 0. This confuses as to why it is maximum at that point? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It could be good if you add the book title and author you are copying this from as reference.

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310613/how-power-dissipation-in-a-transistor-is-less-when-signal-is-present/310691#310691 Any more questions?

Comment: I still have a question about the ic being constant. Why is that? We have a varying input voltage that will cause the collector current to vary around that constant I.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why the maximum instantaneous power dissipated by Q1 is \$P=2V_{cc}*I\$ at RL
>   open?*

\$v_I\$ causes \$v_O\$ to be at a minimum value when \$v_I\$ is at a minimum value. This is because the transistors are basically emitter followers. Under these circumstances, approximately all the supply voltage (\$2\cdot V_{CC}\$) appears across Q1 and so Q1's power dissipation is \$2\cdot V_{CC}\cdot I\$.

It's an approximation because Q2 will never fully turn on to 0 volts and hence, there might be 200 mV less across Q1 and not the full \$2\cdot V_{CC}\$.

Comment: Look at the graph of current ic1 and vec1. the power dissipated should be zero at vce1 = 2Vcc? What am I missing? Also why ice1 is constant I? Wouldn't the vi causes the current to vary as well?

Comment: @Paumdrdo without a load, a class A amplifier draws a constant current that biases the transistors. The current is constant.

Comment: I thought when you have some kind of perturbation at the input the collector current would also have perturbations around its bias point.

Comment: @Paumdrdo - if your done with this question and answer now, please formally accept one of the answers. If not, then raise a comment and ask what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your second yellow highlight to the next comma : it is your answer.

As to why I is constant, it is because Q2 is an (over-simplified) "constant current source" (with some bits missing).

You should already have studied constant current sources before this chapter : the authors clearly assumes you have, so one would like to think they structured the book that way. If not, it would be useful to clarify which book, so that others can avoid it.